# pandas.groupby reacting differently on same data using lambda aggfunc with categorical type vs. object

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

I have encountered some strange behaviour of `pandas.groupby`. Depending on the dtype of my data columns, I get two completely different outcomes. One of them is as expected, the second seems strange.

Data set:

```
country id      plan   consolidation_key
AT01    1000    100    A
AT01    1000    200    B
AT01    2000    300    J
AT01    2000    200    K
```

in an Excel file.

```
import numpy as np

def consolidate(d):
    columns=['country', 'id', 'consolidation_key']
#    columns=['id', 'consolidation_key']
    return d.groupby(by=columns).agg(
        plans=pd.NamedAgg(
            column="plan", aggfunc=lambda s: "-".join(sorted(set(s.astype(str))))
        )
    )

d = pd.read_excel(r"path\to\file\test_data.xlsx", sheet_name='data')

data = d
df = consolidate(data)
print(df)
print("-----------")
print("dtypes:")
print(data.dtypes)
print("--------------------")

data2 = d.assign(country=lambda x: pd.Categorical(x["country"]))
df2 = consolidate(data2)
print(df2)
print("-----------")
print("dtypes:")
print(data2.dtypes)
```

The lambda function in the consolidation does not come fully into play with the example data. It creates a list of unique items (`100-200`).

The result this gives is

```
                               plans
country id   consolidation_key      
AT01    1000 A                   100
             B                   200
        2000 J                   300
             K                   200
-----------
dtypes:
country              object
id                    int64
plan                  int64
consolidation_key    object
dtype: object
--------------------
                               plans
country id   consolidation_key      
AT01    1000 A                   100
             B                   200
             J                   NaN
             K                   NaN
        2000 A                   NaN
             B                   NaN
             J                   300
             K                   200
-----------
dtypes:
country              category
id                      int64
plan                    int64
consolidation_key      object
dtype: object
```

The first consolidation into `df` looks good. The second into `df2` has extra items with `NaN` values. It looks like a cross join for both ids.
Interestingly, this only happens when `columns=['country', 'id', 'consolidation_key']`. With `columns=['id', 'consolidation_key']`, the consolidation works correctly in both cases.

Here is the big question - is this a bug in pandas or do I miss something else?

Versions:

- Python 3.7.3
- IPython 7.8.0
- Pandas 0.25.1 (and 0.25.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading through the posts in @jezrael's answer, I came to an important comment at https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17594#issuecomment-545238294.

Adding `observed=True` to `groupby` solves my problem.

```
def consolidate(d):
columns=['country', 'id', 'consolidation_key']
return d.groupby(by=columns, observed=True).agg(
    plans=pd.NamedAgg(
        column="plan", aggfunc=lambda s: "-".join(sorted(set(s.astype(str))))
    )
)
```